# Trying to prove, by induction, that $2^{4n} + 5 $ is divible by $21.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

I want show by induction

$$ 21 \mid (2^{4n}+5) $$

So I assume:

> $ 2^{4k}+5= 21p$

to prove that $ 21 \mid 2^{4(k+1)}+5 $

So I get it:

$2^{4(k+1)}+5 = 2^{4k+4}+5 = 2^{4k}2^{4}+
2^{4}2^{4k}+5 = 2^{4k} 16 +5 $ =

> $16(2^{4k} +5 -5 )+5 = 16(21p-5)+5 = 16 \cdot 21p - 80+5 = 16 \cdot 21p - 75 $

But its not divisible by 21. Whats I doing wrong ?

Comment: If you put $n=2 \to 2^{4n}+5=261\neq 21p\\n=3 \to 2^{12}+5=4101 \neq 21p \\ n=4 \to 2^{16}+5=65541=21*3121$

Comment: $2^8+5 = 261$ is not divisible by $21$.

Comment: I noticed this issues, by I thought that I made mistake. That example its not corrent at all ?

Comment: It seems $n=1 , 4,7,...$ are ok . so I think $n$ must be in form of $n=3k+1\\k=0,1,2,3,4,...$

Comment: @Khosrotash $21|2^{12k+4}+5?$ Checks out for $k<10,000$ with a little python script.

Comment: @Khosrotash In fact, checks out for $k$ < 100,000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for  $n=2$

$2^{4n}+5=256+5=261$

and

$261=21\times12+9$

so your identity is not true for $n=2$.

Answer (score 1):

**$$ \color{red} {2^{12}=4096=21*195+1}$$
$$2^{12n+4}+5\equiv\\ 2^4 .2^{12n}+5 \equiv\\16.4096^n+5  \equiv\\16 (4095+1)^n+5\equiv\\16.(21.195+1)^n+5 \equiv \\ 16(1)^n+5 \equiv \\21\equiv0$$ so $$21|2^{12n+4}+5\\n=0,1,2,3,4,5,...$$

Answer (score 1):

The statement is true for $n=1$. Suppose it holds for $k$: $2^{4k}+5=21p$, so $2^{4k}=21p-5$, so
$$
2^{4(k+1)}+5=2^{4k}\cdot 16+5=
16(21p-5)+5=21\cdot 16p-80+5=21\cdot16p-75
$$
Ops! Something seems wrong. We have proved that

> if $21\mid 2^{4k}+5$, then $21\nmid 2^{4(k+1)}+5$

Actually, $3\mid 2^{4n}+5$ (prove it), but in general $7\nmid 2^{4n}+5$; indeed,
$$
2^{4n}+5=16^n+5\equiv 2^n+5\equiv2^n-2\equiv2(2^{n-1}-1)\pmod{7}
$$
Now
\begin{align}
2^0-1&\equiv 0\pmod{7}\\
2^1-1&\equiv 1\pmod{7}\\
2^2-1&\equiv 3\pmod{7}\\
2^3-1&\equiv 0\pmod{7}
\end{align}
so $2^{4n}+5$ is divisible by $7$ if and only if $3\mid(n-1)$, therefore when $n=3m+1$, for some $m$.